# Writing and reading int from file after loop

Tags: java, loops, file-io

I'm writing an application that is supposed to act like a cafe clip card. In other words, for every n:th (10 in my case) coffee that a customer purchases, he/she is awarded a free beverage. So, I'm quite done with the loop and I've been working on writing and reading from a file since I need the program to remember where it last left off in order for the customer to be able to close the application once he/she has been in the store. However, I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to write and read from a file, the code I have doesn't seem to output any .txt file. I need the code to have a closing condition, and upon entering this condition, it should write the "count" to a .txt file, and shut down. Once the program is being run the next time it should read from this .txt file so it knows where the count is at.

Here's what I have so far:

public class FelixNeww {

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner key;
    String entry;
    int count = 0;
    String password = "knusan01";
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        key = new Scanner(System.in);
        entry = key.nextLine();
        if(entry.compareTo(password) == 0){
            count++;
            System.out.println("You're one step closer to a free coffe! You have so far bought " 
                    + count + " coffe(s)");
        }
        if(count == 10  && count != 0){
            System.out.println("YOU'VE GOT A FREE COFFE!");
            count = 0;
        }
        if(entry.compareTo(password) != 0){
            System.out.println("Wrong password! Try again.\n");
        }
    }



}

public void saveToFile(int count)
{
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try
    {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("countStorage.txt"))));
        bw.write(count);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(bw != null)
        {
            try
            {
                bw.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}

public int readFromFile()
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(newFileInputStream(new File("countStorage.txt"))));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int count = Integer.parseInt(line);
        return count;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(br != null)
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Is this all your code? Where are you calling the saveToFile and readFromFile methods?

Comment: I'm just starting to learn, I guess I'm not calling it yet?
I started coding java just a few days ago so I'm very inexperienced

Comment: Yes they aren't being called - you should look into the purpose of the "Main Method" in Java and you'll see why. Instead of trying to get it all working at once, you could try reading data from a file first then write to a file after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems here. In your `readFromFile()` method, put a space after the keyword `new`. I also suggest putting a an absolute path for now (for debugging):

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Temp\\countStorage.txt"))));
```

In your `saveToFile()` method, the constructor is wrong. Also put the full path to the file here:

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Temp\\countStorage.txt"));
```

Finally, in your saveToFile() method, write the count as a String. Writing it as an int refers to the Unicode character:

```
 bw.write(Integer.toString(count)); //updated per Hunter McMillen
```

And invoke it...

```
    FelixNeww  f = new FelixNeww();
    f.saveToFile(44);
    System.out.println(f.readFromFile());
```

Comment: I think that `Integer.toString(count)` seems like a more appropriate way to perform that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `readFromFile` or `saveToFile` in the place needed in order to become executed.
I suggest that you call `readFromFile` on the beginning of the `Main` method, use its returning contents, and `saveToFile` in the loop whenever the desired state changes and it needs to be saved.